# How to choose the "family" in gbm.step?

Tags: r, boosting

I try to model species abundance data using the gbm.step function in R by Elith et al. 2008. In this function you have to choose a family aka loss function. There are several options:

- "gaussian" (for minimizing squared error)
- "laplace" (for minimizing absolute loss)
- "bernoulli"  (logistic  regression  for  0-1  out-comes)
- "poisson" (count outcomes; requires the response to be a positive
  integer)

(Look here: [GBM: impact of the loss function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217416/gbm-impact-of-the-loss-function))

As I work with proportional data ranging from 0% to 90% percentage cover of Lupinus nootkatensis (invasive plant species) in 1 gird cell of my abundance raster, gaussian or laplace are the two possibel choices to make. Laplace seems to be more robust against outliers.

1. How do I decide between gaussian and laplace?
2. Is there a rule or is the choice just a matter of taste?

Comment: I think the rule is usually try many different models and pick the one that validates best. See `caret` package

Comment: Usually the context--what you know about the problem and why you're carrying out the analysis--determines the loss.  Even if a different loss might improve cross-validation results, if it's not appropriate for your situation then it's not relevant.

Comment: Thank you Zelazny7 and whuber.      @whuber: Can you please give an example for a context to use laplace and one to use gaussian? The results of the models are very different and not comparable, so one can not decide by using the model fit....

Comment: Gaussian models minimize quadratic losses while Laplace models minimize linear losses.  The latter increase much more rapidly near their optima.  They result in predictions of *medians* rather than *means*.  Especially when response distributions are skewed, the two can be very different.  For instance, if you're analyzing risk to human beings, do you want to protect the largest *number* of people or do you want to minimize the *total harm*?  Deciding between the two is a matter of public policy and ethics, so it would be wrong to make the determination based only on statistical results!

Comment: I want to know 1) what are the key factors driving the distribution of my invasive species and 2) predict where it will occure most likely in the future under chaning climatic conditions for example. So, I want to "minimize the total harm" caused by the invasive species. Thus, I choose gaussian for the family of my gbm, right?